# Blender 3.0, Snap to face + Project individual elements not working as expected

Tags: modeling, snapping, proportional-editing, solidify-modifier, clipping

I have started my quest on making donuts. I have remade this doughnut several times and keep finding the same issue.

When I get to the proportional edit of the icing object it should snap to the side of the doughnut, rather i get clipping though the doughnut and no snap.  I cannot isolate the cause of the issue and consequently have no idea on how to rectify. A search on stack exchange and other websites was unable to shed any further light on the issue.

proportional editing is enabled
Snapping with project individual elements is also enabled.

If anyone is available to help it would be much appreciated.

[image]